# What does "run down a ball" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

What does "run down a ball" mean?

Here's a past tense example, in this comment heard after a tennis match:

> *I can't believe you ran down the last ball.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[To chase and capture](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/run+down)

Comment: Also frequently used in baseball.

Comment: Correct. But the tennis version wouldn't be a chase and capture, but instead a chase and return (hit back).